# Buscar Registro por fecha php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una bd de un diario la cual tiene un caudal bastante amplio de artículos las cuales quiero filtrar por un fecha especifica. el input esta configurado como date ese mismo valor lo guardo en una variable para hacer la consulta pero no me trae la fecha que especifico en el input.
Uds ven algun error en el codigo?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Busqueda</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>




<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">



    <center><h1>Buscador de Ediciones Antiguas</h1></center>
    <br></br>
    <form method="POST" action="registro.php" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doc">Fecha del Diario</label>
   <br></br>  
        <input type="text" value="" name="fechab" class="form-control" id="fechab" min="2004-11-19">
   <br></br>
    <center>
      <input type="submit" value="Consultar" class="btn btn-info" name="btn2">
      <input type="submit" value="Volver" class="btn btn-info" name="btnv">
    </center>

  </form>



  <?php



    if(isset($_POST['btn2']))

    {
      include("abrir_conexion.php");

        $fechab=($_POST['fechab']);
        if($fechab=="") 
          {echo "Ingrese una fecha";}
        else
        {  
          $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT fecha,titulo,textobreve,textolargo FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE fecha = $fechab");
            echo $fechab;
            while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
          {
            echo 
            "
              <table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\">
                <tr>
                <td><b><center>fecha</center></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>".$consulta['fecha']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><b><center>titulo</center></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>".$consulta['titulo']."</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                  <td><b><center>textocorto</center></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>".$consulta['textobreve']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                  <td><b><center>textolargo</center></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>".$consulta['textolargo']."</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            ";
          }
        }

      include("cerrar_conexion.php");
    }
  ?>



  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bien venido a [es.so]. Dos cosillas que he visto a primera vista, lo primero es que las fechas deben ser enviases en la consulta como String por lo que deben ir entre comillas, también indicar que tu consulta es vulnerable a inyección SQL. Ademas la variable `$tabla_db1` no veo que este definida en ningún lugar.

Comment: Recuerda que tu campo en tu base de datos debe ser date y no varchar, y que las fechas que se envian deben ser en formato inglés (yyyy/mm/dd) y no en formatos español (dd/mm/yyyy). Suerte ;).

Answer (score 0):

empeza por cambiar:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="fechab"...
```

por:

```
<input type="date" name="fechab"...
```

luego en el php te hace falta alguna funcion que verifique si la fecha es valida y tiene el formato que acepta mysql -> aaaa-mm-dd

Comment: Debes colocar también la respuesta para el lado de PHP, no solo mencionarlo

Comment: Bueno la pregunta no es por una funcion que valide fechas. Eso mas que ayuda, es un curso shadow.

Comment: tu respuesta esta a medias por eso